# The buffer partition of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-layout

In Matlab the buffer of matrix is continuous in column . So what about the numpy array of Python. which one is beter between `numpy.empty((n,1))` and `numpy.empty((1,n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numpy` you can choose between `Fortran-contiguous` (along the column, like in Matlab) and `C-contiguous` (along the row, which is the default in numpy) order, [passing the `order` argument when you create an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), so you have more flexibility.

As @user2357112 already said, for a 1xN or Nx1 array it does not matter, but for a MXN array it does matter and you should be aware of that.

Comment: Is the C-contiguous  the default `order` argument.

Answer (score 0):

They do different things. One makes an Nx1 array; the other makes a 1xN array. Neither is "better". (In fact, the memory layout will be identical for both arrays, even if you specify column-major storage.)

To answer the question about storage layout, though, numpy defaults to row-major layout, a.k.a. C-contiguous. You can see this clearly reflected in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html).

Comment: And if you specify fortran-layout, whatever numpy routine you use will still return you something in default order (so fortran-layout seems pretty pointless to me)

Comment: @usethedeathstar you need Fortran layout when you are using for example `BLAS` routines programmed in Fortran, so this layout can be very useful

Comment: @SaulloCastro how do you access those routines from numpy? Is there a fortran version of things like numpy.sqrt(x) or whatever you wish to do? Or do you mean if you would work with f2py or so?

Comment: @usethedeathstar you can have a look [at this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153914/832621) for futher information... this can considerably speed up your code, but you should worry about this only for heavy tasks...[I adapted this from pv for a faster `dot()`](https://gist.github.com/saullocastro/6388865) when calling from Cython